# How does one craft an array from LEFT JOINs when joined tables have multiple matches and GROUP BY omits needed rows

Tags: php, mysql

I was presented with something PHP/MYSQL related today that I was unsure exactly how to approach.

I am running this query against an altered vbulletin database:

```
SELECT
        p.postid, 
        p.threadid, 
        p.parentid, 
        p.username, 
        p.title, 
        p.dateline, 
        p.pagetext, 
        p.allowsmilie,
        p.visible,

        pe.post_type, 
        pe.element_type, 
        pe.element, 

        pr.region_id,

        th.threadid,
        th.title,
        th.forumid,
        th.lastpost,
        th.lastposter,
        th.lastpostid,
        th.similar,

        at.contentid,
        at.attachmentid,

        p.attach


    FROM thread AS th

    JOIN post as p ON p.threadid = th.threadid
    LEFT JOIN post_element AS pe ON pe.post_id = p.postid
    LEFT JOIN post_region AS pr ON pr.post_id = p.postid
    LEFT JOIN attachment AS at ON at.contentid = p.postid

GROUP BY p.postid;
```

The issue with the above is that sometimes there is 2, 3, or 4 rows from post_element that have the same post_id == p.postid. In that case the GROUP BY returns the 1st match and omits the 2nd 3rd....etc....

What I really desire is to create an array in something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

}
```

that builds nested arrays for the pe.element, pe.post_type, pe.element_type fields when there is more than one match on post_id.

I was able to hack this by using this:

```
SELECT
        p.postid, 
        p.threadid, 
        p.parentid, 
        p.username, 
        p.title, 
        p.dateline, 
        p.pagetext, 
        p.allowsmilie,
        p.visible,

        group_concat(pe.post_type) as post_type, 
        group_concat(pe.element_type) as element_type, 
        group_concat(pe.element) as element, 

        group_concat(pr.region_id) as region_id,

        th.threadid,
        th.title,
        th.forumid,
        th.lastpost,
        th.lastposter,
        th.lastpostid,
        th.similar,

        at.contentid,
        at.attachmentid,

        p.attach


    FROM thread AS th

    JOIN post as p ON p.threadid = th.threadid
    LEFT JOIN post_element AS pe ON pe.post_id = p.postid
    LEFT JOIN post_region AS pr ON pr.post_id = p.postid
    LEFT JOIN attachment AS at ON at.contentid = p.postid

GROUP BY p.postid'
```

and then 
    $row['element'] = explode(",", $row['element']);

inside of the aforementioned mysql_fetch_assoc while loop...

but how would you craft an array with PHP that has only one $row for each post_id == postid with a nested array for fields that have multiple matches from $result?

Many Many thanks for your brainPower!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would select the first as you are currently, add a `count(pe.post_id)` to the query and if that number is greater than 1, theuy just query that table directly

If > 50% have more than 1 then always use the second query and never check for it.

so

```
//do main query
foreach($post as &$p) {
   $elements = array();
   $p['elements'] = getElements($p['postid'])
}
```